# cmake gui gives Unknown CMake command "CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS"

Tags: android, cmake

I am trying to compile LibTiff For Android so found the source code with Cmake scripts

https://bitbucket.org/edgarv/libtiff-cmake here when I try to run cmake script from cmake-gui it gives error like below

```
Unknown CMake command "CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS"
```

I tried to search on google but didnt got any proper answer about how to resolve it.

Comment: I looked at that repository briefly through the web interface and it appears that there are missing files for the cmake configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS` is function from [CheckLibraryExists](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#module%3aCheckLibraryExists) module. You need to include     correspond module to use it:

```
include(CheckLibraryExists)
CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS(...)
```

If you're using third-party code, take a look at include error messages. May be some modules not found and failed to include, otherwise it is bug.